# Who is the pioneer of the RAM concept?

Tags: shiva, rama

Hindu mythology says that Vishnu (or RAM) resides in everyone's heart. Scriptures also say that Shiva meditates on the Ram form of Vishnu.

But, who brought into the universe the concept of RAM for the first time?? Was Shiva brought in the concept during the early stages of the universe??

Comment: The Supreme Person resides in a small lotus in everyone's heart.He is not necessarily Sri Rama.The Yogis or Sanyasi meditate upon this Supreme Being . and for them he is Maheswara or Lord Shiva.Actually my Ista Devta reside in my heart urs reside in ur heart and so on.

Comment: @Rickross: But, the supreme personality is Lord Narayana, as said in Gita.....Even Shiva meditates upon him....

Comment: There are many other Gitas&each depicts one Deity as Supreme.And all of these Gitas are true.So what are we to make out of this?I have just quoted from the Sanyasa Suktam(a Vedic Hymn).If u want i can give you the exact verses.Actually one's Istha Devata resides in one's heart.

Comment: @Indu For Vaishnavas Vishnu is the Supreme but for Shaivas Shiva is Supreme. So Vishnu and Shiva meditate on each other. And yes Lord Shiva is the preceptor of Rama Nama.

Comment: Plus I don't understand what you mean by Ram Concept. What is 'Concept' exactly over here?

Comment: Please do some research and edit your question. Lord Rama walked this planet.

Answer (score 4):

There is not such thing as First Time in Sanatan Dharma...

**Sanatana Dharma = Eternal Religion**

We can not trace the origin of anything here.

In what Refrence we can call First Time?

If we assume that concept of Ram came just after his incarnation then also we can not trace origin of his incarnation..
_______________________________________
If we assume Lord Rama came in 24th Treta in this Manwantar. Then we are right. But it is not his first incarnation. Before these kalpas also there were incarnations of Lord Rama and Ramayan happened. For eg. Padma Purana Patala Khanda chapter 116 gives detailed story of Ramayan of previous kalpa.
Hence **one can not trace the information of origin of incarnation too..**
_______________________________________
If we tell who pioneered in the first Kalpa ie. Brahma kalpa of Brahma then also that is not origin of that concept. Before that Brahma also there were many Brahmas. We can't take a refrence point for the time. And  hence we can't trace the origin.
_______________________________________
This question is like
 **"When was first soul created ?**

These types of question can't be explained in terms of time. They go back and back and back. Hence they are called eternal.

Hence there is no such thing as pioneer of Ram concept..
_______________________________________
Concept/Knowledge of Rama is eternal so is our soul too... **From Advaita Perspective** as our soul is non different from supreme soul we possess all knowledge including concept of Rama, Brahmn and all things. **Hence one can not give knowledge to another person, he/she can only remove ignorance from that person because the person is himself fully knowledgeable being non different from Supreme. So we all from eternity possess the concept of Rama.**
_______________________________________
Hence, *If we know then we can not call it pioneered, we have simply removed veil of ignorance...*

Answer (score 3):

First of all your question is not that clear.But inspite of that let me try to answer it.Let's hope that it clears some of your doubts.

Who resides in our heart is your first question.So,let me answer that first.

Let's take the Sanyasa Suktam from the MahaNarayanopanishad as found [here](http://mathrusrisarada.org/Na%20Karma%20Na%20in%20English.htm) .Quoting from the last two verses :

> Dahraṁ vipāpaṁ parameśmabhūtaṁ
>
> Yatpuṇḍarīkaṁ puramadhya saggaṁstham |
>
> Tatrāpi dahraṁ gaganaṁ viśoka
>
> Stasmin yadantasta-dupāsitavyam |3|
>
> Yo vedādau svaraḥ prokto
>
> Vedānte ca pratiṣṭitaḥ |
>
> Tasya prakṛati līnasya
>
> Yaḥ parassa **maheśvaraḥ** |4|

Meaning-In the citadel of the body there is the small sinless & pure lotus of the heart which is the residence of the Supreme Person.Further in the interior of this small area there is the sorrowless ether.This is to be meditated upon continually. |3|

He is **Maheswaraha**(Lord Shiva) who transcends the syllable OM which is uttered at the commencement of the recital of the Vedas which is well established in the Upanishads & which alone remains after the final dissolution.|4|

So,according to Sanyasa Suktam Lord Shiva(Maheswarah) resides in our heart.
 and who is the object of meditation of the Sanyasis.

Now, if you read the [Narayana Suktam](http://www.swami-krishnananda.org/invoc/in_nara.html) it also says almost the same thing in a slightly different way.

[image]

[image]

So,i have quoted from the most authoritative scriptures ,the Vedas, to show what it says about who resides in our heart.Its basically God who resides in it,& who is one but we know Him by different names.

So ,you can say that Shiva resides or Narayana resides ,the meaning both being just the same.

Now, coming to your second question regarding who first emphasized the glory of Rama Nama.

It was Lord Shiva.

Quoting from [this](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Vishnu_Sahasranamam) page:

> The Vishnu Sahasranam is found in the Mahabharatha. Literally
>   translated this means thousand names of Vishnu. This is found in the
>   Anushasanika Parvam (chapter relating to orders or rules to the kings)
>   of Mahabharatha. ......... In the afterward to the stotra Goddess
>   Parvathi asks Siva the cosmic god for an easy way to sing this stotra
>   for the learned. **He replies that it is sufficient that the learned
>   one repeats the name of Rama and this is equivalent to his singing of
>   sahasranama. It is important to note that this is easy method is
>   prescribed to the very learned who do not have time to recite it daily
>   and not for everybody,**

The greatness of Rama Nama is also described in the [Bhavisya Purana](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/bhavishya/bookview.php?chapnum=25) as follows:

> Rama namahi tat jnyeyam Sarvaaghouga vinashanam (Rama nama itself
>   would destrory all the sins).

Comment: #Rockross: Absolute answer. Thanks. That is what Krishna said to Arjun while showing his Virat form. That he is the Supreme being, He is Shiva, He is Vishnu, He is Brahma etc.

Comment: @InduBhusanNath, if you liked the answer then you may want to accept it by clicking "right check" below the voting points. Same holds true for all your previous Qs, where you felt satisfied. Once done, it concludes that you have got the correct answer. This is a well accepted etiquette in SE forums.